# Reverse bias p-n junction diode and Kinetic energy

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, quantum-tunneling

In reverse bias p-n junction diode, which energy is lower than the energy of the potential barrier: the average kinetic energy of the would-be-tunnelling electrons or the kinetic energy of the individual/particular tunnelling electron?

Answer (score 0):

The spread in the energies of the electrons comes from thermal excitations so we expect it to be around $kT$. At room temperature this is around $0.025$ eV, so unless we are dealing with very small barriers it is so small it can be ignored. Effectively all the electrons have the same energy.

This means that we cannot explain the tunnelling by electrons occasionally getting an energy higher than the barrier. To a good approximation either all the electrons have energies higher than the barrier or none do. The tunneling we see in for example reverse biased (low voltage¹) zener diodes is genuinely a quantum phenomenon.

---

¹ Note that in high voltage zener diodes the reverse bias conduction is due to a form of dielectric breakdown not tunneling.

Comment: Without doing the math, how do you know that the barrier is so big that 0.025 eV, could be ignored?

Comment: Because the barrier is about a volt i.e. 40 times $kT$. That means the percentage of electrons with an energy greater than the barrier is about $e^{-40}$, and that's an exceedingly small number!